# how to add mat select in Angular input

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, html-select

I'm finding away to add mat select on my input field but some reason when I click on the arrow, it's not working and not showing me all the list.

I have autocomplete and usually when a user start typing it show all the list to select but I'm trying add mat-select also so that user can just click on the arrow and select from the list without having to type something first.

I've followed below stackblitz example ( checkbox is not needed for mine) but mine is little bit different and I also have text input and auto complete so I'm not sure why I can't type anymore in my input with current code and also the drop down list are not showing when I click the arrow.

any suggestion or help will be really apprecaited.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-v9-mat-select-with-mat-chip-list?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.html

```
    <mat-form-field class="form" appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Search or Select a Super Tag</mat-label>

        <mat-select [formControl]="superTags" multiple>
            <mat-select-trigger>
                <mat-chip-list #chipList>
                    <div>
                        <mat-chip *ngFor="let superTag of superTags" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable"
                            (removed)="remove(superTag)">
                            <img class="super-icon" src="/assets/images/icons/super-tag-icon.svg">
                            {{superTag.tag}}
                            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable" matTooltip="Remove a super tag">cancel</mat-icon>
                        </mat-chip>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input matInput  #input [(ngModel)]="tagIn" [formControl]="tagCtrl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                            [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes" (matChipInputTokenEnd)="addTag()">

                    </div>
                </mat-chip-list>
                <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
                    <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-Loading">
                        <mat-spinner diameter="20"></mat-spinner>
                    </mat-option>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of filteredSuperTags | async" [value]="tag">
                            {{tag}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </ng-container>
                </mat-autocomplete>
            </mat-select-trigger>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

Comment: try ng-select library https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/data-sources

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would not use the combination of chip list and autocomplete.

I think, what you really need, is the autocomplete with options which contain checkboxes for the multiselect. Try to do, somethihg like this.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select Users" aria-label="Select Users" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="userControl">
  <mat-hint>Enter text to find users by name</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let user of filteredUsers | async" [value]="selectedUsers">
        <div (click)="optionClicked($event, user)">
            <mat-checkbox [checked]="user.selected" (change)="toggleSelection(user)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
                {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
            </mat-checkbox>
        </div>
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Full example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sx79hu?embed=1&file=app/multiselect-autocomplete-example.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the example but I forgot to mentions that I don't really need checkbox inside the dropdown list and I just only need the arrow icon so that user can click to show drop down list. I tried to use Mat-Select because that's how I was able to show arrow icon right now but the problem I have is I can't type anymore and the drop down list are not showing when I click the arrow icon. thx

Comment: Also, After user search and press enter or select from the drop down list, It supposed to create a chips so I'm not sure If I can just remove the Chip List. thx

Comment: So why can't you just use basic mat-autocomplete ? There are good examples in NG Docs.

Anyway you can customize your mat autocomplete however you want.
Add (keyup.enter)="enterPressedMethod()" into <input> element to determine what component function is being called after enter.

You can also add a custom placeholder , or add custom Arrow Icon next to Autocomplete input, and set (click)="arrowClicked()" function in which you will make something like Autocomplete.Focus

Comment: I’m really new to Angular and working on existing code base so I’m still kinda lost. By anychance can you show me using my code? I’ll be really appreciated if you can help me adding arrow icon on right and also the input and drop down list to work. Thx